# Monte Carlo simulation dices in python

Tags: python, math, montecarlo

I have a question related to Monte Carlo simulation based on the probability of rolling 2 dices. How can you present when coding in python the fact that the sum is larger than n and smaller than m? As an example I made this in mathlab:

```
NT = 10^5; %number of throws
log = zeros(1,12);
for throw = 1:NT
    dices = ceil(6*rand(1,2));
    s = sum(dices);
    log(s) = log(s)+1;
end
p = 36*log(6:9)/NT;
s1 = sum(round(p))
```

In the above example I presumed that n is 5 and m is 10.

Thank you

Comment: `import numpy as np; np.random.randint(low=1, high=7, size=2)` this will produce `[i,j]` array that represent the 2 dice you can use `sum([..])` to get the sum of those rolls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop you want to simulate two separate random dice throws.  My following snippet uses a `list` (you can use a `dict` if you like) to store the results of `NT` simulations:

```
import random

num_throws = 10**5  # NT
roll_log = [0] * 12  # Generate list for dice roll tallies

for i in range(num_throws):
    # Random integer between 1 and 6 inclusive for each dice
    dice_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice_2 = random.randint(1, 6)

    # Sum the random dice and increment the tally for that particular roll total
    roll_sum = dice_1 + dice_2
    roll_log[roll_sum-1] += 1  # minus 1 because Python is 0-indexed
```

To process your resulting data you can access the tally for a particular dice roll in the results list by `roll_log[roll-1]` where `2 <= roll <= 12` (`roll = 1` will have a probability of zero since it is impossible with 2+ dice).  The following for-loop is just an example of how you can access the results of `NT` simulations if you are unfamiliar with enumeration in Python:

```
for i, tally in enumerate(roll_log):
    roll_prob = float(tally) / num_throws  # Experimental probability of roll
    roll = i + 1  # Since Python lists are 0-indexed
    print('{}: {}/{} = {}'.format(roll, tally, num_throws, roll_prob))
```

Output:

```
1: 0 / 100000 = 0
2: 2741 / 100000 = 0.02741
3: 5518 / 100000 = 0.05518
4: 8202 / 100000 = 0.08202
5: 11235 / 100000 = 0.11235
6: 14046 / 100000 = 0.14046
7: 16520 / 100000 = 0.1652
8: 13799 / 100000 = 0.13799
9: 11025 / 100000 = 0.11025
10: 8459 / 100000 = 0.08459
11: 5672 / 100000 = 0.05672
12: 2783 / 100000 = 0.02783
```

Specifically addressing the last part of your question, finding the probability of the dice roll being between `n = 5` and `m = 10` not inclusive, this can be done using a method called *list slicing*:

```
n = 5
m = 10
                                 #    6      7      8      9
rolls_between = roll_log[n:m-1]  # [14046, 16520, 13799, 11025]
sum_rolls_between = sum(rolls_between)  # 55390
prob_between = float(sum_rolls_between) / num_throws  # 0.5539
```

**Note:**  The `float` conversion of either `sum_rolls_between` or `num_throws` on the last line is essential to obtain a decimal output, because division between two integers in Python always results in an integer output after applying mathematical `floor()` function.  In other words, without changing one of those two values to a floating point value, the result will be 0.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It is very nicely explained. May I also ask if there were n number of dice, what would be the situation? Do you use a float conversion or just assume that there are a number of dice like 10 ** 6 or 10 ** 7?

Comment: For the answer I have provided the only change you would have to make would be to `NT`.  The float conversion is necessary if you want to obtain a decimal answer from division involving two integer values, regardless of what the two values actually are.  Example: `3 / 2 = 1`, `3.0 / 2 = 1.5`, `3 / 2.0 = 1.5`.

Answer (score 1):

See below-

```
import numpy as np
NT = 10**5
n=5
m=10
x = np.random.randint(1, 12, NT)
s = sum((x>=n) & (x<=m))
p = s*1.0/NT
print(p)
```

Comment: Where does it states that there are 2 dices? I don't see any info related to that. Is it given in this formula: p = s*1.0/NT where "1.0" states the number of dices?

Comment: Since I am taking the random numbers (integers) between 1 to 11 that does simulates the actual dice sum which can vary between 2 to 12.

Comment: @Aritesh: You're generating a *uniformly distributed* integer between 1 and 11 (inclusive). The sum of two dice is *not* uniformly distributed, so you can't use `randint(1, 12)` to model it.